# Using auto for a defined function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've used `auto` to store a lambda that is constructed right in the auto assignment, but today I was looking at [this interesting paper on functional programming using c++ templates](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~hxt/2015/c-plus-plus/intro-to-templates.pdf) and came across this code:

```
template < typename T , typename Ops >
T fold ( Linked <T > * p )
{
   T acc = Ops :: initial () ;
   while ( p ) {
     acc = Ops :: bin ( acc , p - > head ) ;
     p = p - > tail ;
   }
   return acc ;
}

// later, in main():

auto sumup = fold <int , IntOps >;
```

I am trying to understand what the type of `sumup` would be, since it is assigned not to the output of `fold` but rather to the actual function `fold` itself! I decided to take a look at the various ways `auto` is shown to be used [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). I am assuming that this use of `auto` falls under `(1)` on that page, a general variable initializer. What is not clear is what is the type of `sumup`?

And, would `auto` potentially be the same here as doing this:

```
   using functionType = int (Linked<int>*);
   functionType sumup = fold <int , IntOps >;
```

This is probably not correct, but I'd be curious if my thinking is in the right direction. When instantiated, `fold <int , IntOps >` will be a function that returns an `int` and taking a single argument of `Linked<int>*`, so my `using` declaration is saying the same thing? Is this `using` declaration a bonafide "type" and is the `auto` arriving at the same deduction as this `using`?

Comment: Very close. Plain `auto` decays, so you get a function pointer type - `int (*)(Linked<int>*)`

Comment: Since you have the answer, I'd like to say that I find the withdom of this code questionable. Someone will have hard time figuring out what this `sumup` is.

Comment: @SergeyA true, and in fact that is a general weakness with implicit type deduction in any language. It gets much worse in a dynamic language. I still find I prefer explicit type declaration except in cases where this is hard to know and better left to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While every function has a type, you cannot have expressions of that type, nor variables. So `int foo(float)` has type `int(float)`, for instance, but you cannot have a variable of that type.

You **can** have expressions and variables of type **pointer to** function, so `int(*)(float)`. For instance, `&foo` is such a pointer to function.

The two types are quite closely related, obviously. In fact, the conversion is implicit: `int (*pFoo)(float) = foo;` does the conversion automatically.

What you do here is pretty much the same: `int (*sumup)(Linked<int>*) =  fold <int , IntOps >;`. You see that `auto` makes the definition much more readable.

Comment: You can definitely have expressions of function type.

Comment: @T.C.: Example? A _function call expression_ does not have function type.

Comment: `int foo(float);`, the id-expression `foo` is an lvalue of function type `int(float)`.

Comment: @T.C.: Good example, that `id-expression` has to have function type in order to support references to functions. And I think that `(foo)` is another expression with function type. But `+foo` no longer has function type.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` works by the same rules as [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). That is, when unqualified, it will take things by value. Since here you're returning a function reference, it will have to decay down to a pointer, because there's no "value type" for a function, with a specific size and whatnot.

You could also capture with `auto&&` which would make the type of `sumup` be `int (&)(Linked<int>*)`, i.e. a reference to the function.